# Colab error Sorry, no backends available. Please try again later. More info

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've been getting the error for the second day now:

```
Sorry, no backends available. Please try again later.
More info
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjkLY.png)

at first I thought it was a Google system error (since this is also observed in other IT corporations)

but then I decided to check on other accounts all the same, this is a serious mistake.
all my links. According to the specified source in the [GitHub](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1287), I indicate links

```
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lkaX5W6mkuzTuYG6whZteSD3wtArMDxR
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10ScKrC_1zDAdUI_fixXouaRDI-jvLiVi
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xOAmPNK_MVfYbHhqNExelwbcrSw83xXi
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1S7A3KTu9VvRR1zqlK_YhSfYYuleAxQVv
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LyLiTXiT9LrNyw2CWw0Hk5MqMEj0tlSU
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jTehoIa0FOfjPiNDjjBXgyRyfVBjfule
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MlIywMpgSKLNVey9s3xCp6kiziqGAhdW
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10dUbKZ6LawjdWpF9zRY2UxRF6injtFzF
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16CruynjejPUIqJFzRfnewu2nlHEESt1z
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15pBJpdOEc7N7D_ulsFQZSkamm3L8f961
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XKKpQPKyk0QHOoQqEGixHuXtnCG5AsyL
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dic1c42xQOhImgSI_bs-4NCJ5YpQXaZ-
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xwkhkdrAxuWilQwZOze-GTDkaJRWHfMW
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13EWIEB0N_1zMxWiP6vJ4pToxKgiwDZDb
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JZnD_Jz7KnWrQy2n020ntMJA2Njs2gHx
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13h73A2JzCS1X4xPpSW_bGqkqotEid4rT
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to resource limits as mentioned in [this link](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#resource-limits).

Quick Solution:

- Share your colab notebook with another google account you own with edit access.
- Edit the colab notebook from that account.

It worked for me.

More information on Resource limits:

GPUs and TPUs are sometimes prioritized for users who use Colab interactively rather than for long-running computations, or for users who have recently used fewer resources in Colab. As a result, users who use Colab for long-running computations, or users who have recently used more resources in Colab, are more likely to run into usage limits and have their access to GPUs and TPUs temporarily restricted.